# Create a new loop without quotation marks

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I wrote a function on python that should print the sentences below.

```
def write_to_file(matrix, path): 
    f = open(path, "w")
    f.write('\r\n')
    for i in range (2,5):
      item = (bestQuarterRate(matrix, i)) 
      item = (str(item))
      print item
      f.write(item)
    f.close()
```

The problem is that I get this:

```
('Highest quarter rate is between', '1/1/15', 'and', '1/3/15', 'with rate:', 924.9966666666666)
('Highest quarter average exchange change is between', '1/4/15', 'and', '1/6/15', 'with rate:', 598.1673333333333)
('Highest quarter volume is between', '1/4/13', 'and', '1/6/13', 'with rate:', 158.7078934137758)
```

and I need to change it to this:

```
Highest quarter rate is between 1/1/15 and 1/3/15 with rate: 924.996666667

Highest quarter average exchange is between 1/10/14 and 1/12/14 with rate: 1503.67333333

Highest quarter volume change rate is between 1/4/13 and 1/6/13 with rate: 158.707893414

The best year is 2014 with an average exchange value of: $1601932.83452
```

I would like to get any help.

Comment: Evidently `bestQuarterRate` returns a **tuple** - if you want to make it a single string, you can use e.g. `' '.join(item)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `item` is a `tuple`:

```
>>> item = ('Highest quarter rate is between', '1/1/15', 'and', '1/3/15', 'with rate:', 924.9966666666666)
```

The `str`ing version of a tuple is its `repr`esentation, for example:

```
>>> str(item)
"('Highest quarter rate is between', '1/1/15', 'and', '1/3/15', 'with rate:', 924.9966666666666)"
```

Instead, you want to convert each element in the tuple to a string, then join all of these strings together into a single string:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, item))
'Highest quarter rate is between 1/1/15 and 1/3/15 with rate: 924.996666667'
```

For further explanation, see the documentation on [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Answer (score -1):

You have to join the `item` tuple like so `item = ' '.join(item)`.

Full code:

```
def write_to_file(matrix, path): 
    f = open(path, "w")
    f.write('\r\n')
    for i in range (2,5):
        item = (bestQuarterRate(matrix, i)) 
        print item
        item = ' '.join(item)
        f.write(item)
    f.close()
```

Comment: This won't work correctly, because you've converted `item` to a string first, so you'll get e.g. `"( ' H i g h e s t   q u a r t e r   r a t e   i s   b e t w e e n ' ,   ' 1 / 1 / 1 5 ' ,   ' a n d ' ,   ' 1 / 3 / 1 5 ' ,   ' w i t h   r a t e : ' ,   9 2 4 . 9 9 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 )"`...

Comment: I didn't notice that in the original code. Nice catch! Fixed it :)